# React navigation + managing navigation state

Tags: reactjs

I am building a React.js application for web and mobile, I am not planning on using React Native for now.

I am still quite new to building react apps so this is mainly a question about best practices and/or any tools I should be aware of.

I have pretty standard use cases for navigation.
Basically I have some data objects which can be identified by an id and I want to navigate between different views of these objects.

E.g: myapp.com/viewA/123 (where 123 is the id of some object accessed by my api)

I plan to store my navigation state in Apollo Client cache as I am already using it for my api data.

So something like this in my Apollo Client cache

```
Navigation:{
   selectedDataEntity: 123,       
   previosDataEntities; [456,789],
   selectedView:viewA
}
```

I can use a componentDidMount method to update my navigation state from the url if someone is deeplinking into my app.

Then I could have a hoc withNavigation which I could use to provide props like selectedId (and maybe later have functions in there like navigateToPrevious)

I am just wondering if this is a good idea?

Are there any libraries I should be aware of (that might give be navigateBack/forward functionality out of the box for example).

Thanks,

Comment: are you using react-router already?  it sounds like that's what you're looking for

Comment: I am yes. But I'm more asking about storing navigation state. Like if i have 2 views that should 'remember' where they were and navigate independently. A bit like on Facebook if you search for a friend and then go to your feed, if you go back to friends you are automatically navigated back to where you previously were.